# Is it possible to partially build a pydantic basemodel before validation?

Tags: python, validation, pydantic

Working on a data access package which handles queries from a database and should return `pydantic` models.

**Here is the Problem:**
Most of the models are derived from multiple tables. This means after querying a models table, do not yet have all of the models properties (I first have to query them from tables which are given by foreign keys for example).

**Current (bad) solution**
Currently I have simply solved this by making the properties `Optional` and constructing the model in steps. The database queries are set to return dictionaries, so I use `model_validate()` to instantiate the models. Here is an example:

```
with self.connection.cursor(dictionary=True, buffered=True) as cursor:
    cursor.execute(
        query,
    )
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    datasets = []
    while isinstance(result, dict):
        dataset = DatasetModel.model_validate(result)
        dataset.format = FormatModel.model_validate(result)
        dataset.scans = self.scan_access.get(
            dataset_ids=[result["dataset_id"]]
        )
        result = cursor.fetchone()
```

The issue with this is, that in fact these properties are **not** optional and in the code using the package a lot of asserts are needed to keep the IDE quiet (I am using types, black, ruff,...)

Other solutions I thought of but don't like are tinkering with the results dictionary (adding all properties), before calling `model_validate()` or creating separate models mirroring the respective tables (both seem like a bit too much hassle tbh).

So the question is simple: Is it possible to construct the model partially and do the validation only when it is completed?